# Cannot figure out how to write data to NFC type 4 tag with C# pcsc

Tags: c#, nfc, apdu, ndef, pcsc

I'm writing an application in c# .net that needs to communicate with nfc reader (ACR122U or in built windows WUDC).
The reader will send/receive data to wristband that behaves like type 4 tag. I'm using pcsc sharp library for this: https://github.com/danm-de/pcsc-sharp.
Communication is over NDEF protocol with single text record, which can be used to obtain data from wristband. Text record format is *G:{nameOfParameter}*. For example *G:ID*, *G:MAC*.

I'm struggling for few days with sending write message to the wristband. The command I was able to make work is APDU ReadBinary Command:

```
using var isoReader = new IsoReader(context, readerName, SCardShareMode.Shared, SCardProtocol.T1);
var command = new CommandApdu(IsoCase.Case2Extended, isoReader.ActiveProtocol)
{
   CLA = 0x00,
   P1 = 0x00,
   P2 = 0x00,
   Le = 0x24,
   Instruction = InstructionCode.ReadBinary
};

var response = isoReader.Transmit(command);
```

Which converts to: 00-B0-00-00-00-00-24

And received data is: 00-14-C1-01-00-00-00-0D-54-02-65-6E-47-3A-49-44-3A-36-35-35-33-35-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00. Which contains NDEF text message with G:ID:65535 (which is an expected value).

I tried sending APDU UpdateBinary command to send data (where data is single ndef text record with enG:ID as payload):

```
new CommandApdu(IsoCase.Case3Extended, protocol)
{
   Data = new byte[] { 0xC1, 0x01, 0x06, 0x54, 0x65, 0x6E, 0x47, 0x3A, 0x49, 0x44 },
   CLA = 0x00,
   P1 = 0x00,
   P2 = 0x00,
   Instruction = InstructionCode.UpdateBinary // D6
};
```

But I'm getting 0B 00 which translates to "wrong parameters P1-P2" according to https://www.eftlab.com/knowledge-base/complete-list-of-apdu-responses/

I've done some testing with android NFC Tools application. I can create there a NDEF message with single text record (for example G:MAC or G:ID) and send it to the wristband (using the application UI). After that next read wristband gives proper value in response (ID or MAC depending on last sent command).
So it seems communication using NFC Tools app works correctly.

Other info that I get from NFC Tools about tag:
Tag type: ISO 14443-4
Technologies: IsoDep, NfcA, Ndef
Data format: NFC Forum Type 4

Could someone point me in right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Type 4 NDef Spec might help at https://web.archive.org/web/20190827131645/http://apps4android.org/nfc-specifications/NFCForum-TS-Type-4-Tag_2.0.pdf

I assume you have done all the file select stuff correctly

but the update procedure in the spec says

> The NDEF update procedure is:
>
> 1. If the length of the NDEF message (to be written) is bigger than Maximum NDEF size-2 (see NFC File Control TLV in Section 5.1.2.1), the NDEF update procedure is aborted. Otherwise, go to item 2.
> 2. Write the value 0000h in the NLEN field (see Table 9) using the NDEF Update command.
> 3. Write the NDEF message in the NDEF message field (see Table 9) using one or more NDEF Update commands.
> 4. Write the length of the NDEF message in the NLEN field (see Table 9) using the NDEF Update command.

It seems as the NLEN field has a size then your offset should never be zero but `2h`

I've not tried this with Type 4 Tags but thought the spec might help you.

Comment: Thanks for help! I've managed to figure it out based on the documentation and your hint. I was missing NLEN in the command bytes.

Comment: If it helped answer your question please mark it as answered, thanks